# Aggregate functions in Java streams

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, aggregate-functions

I don't know why I should use aggregate functions.
I mean, it is supposed that an aggregate function would parallelize the execution if improves the performance.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html

But it is not true, according to the documentation, the code won't be parallel if you do not use a parallelStream() instead stream(), so 
Why should I use a stream() if nothing goes better?

Shouldn't those codes be the same?

```
//it is not parallel
listOfIntegers.stream()
            .forEach( e -> System.out.print(e+" "));
```

And

```
//it is parallel
listOfIntegers.parallelStream()
            .forEach( e -> System.out.print(e+" "));
```

Comment: What do you mean with "aggregate" functions? Usage of streams?

Comment: You are using lambda-expressions in your Statements. Do you mean map, filter, reduce as aggregate-functions?

Comment: `forEach` is not an aggregate function. Besides that, in your example you most likely want to use `stream()` instead of `parallelStream()` because the sequential `stream()` will be faster in most cases.

Comment: @Holger, `forEach()` is an aggregate operation, at least in some sense, because it is referred to as such in the tutorial. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html

Comment: Yes, Java call the operations in a stream "aggregate functions", https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html

Comment: The question for me is: why should I use aggregate functions if they don't improve the performance by parallelizing the load?, I understand them as a way to do so, It is an unordered stream  that perform operations in a collection. I understand it means it will parallelize the work, but it is not parallel unless you say so explicit.

Answer (score 2):

if you use `stream`, all data in your list will be processed in order, while if you use `parallelStream` your data might not be process in order.

consider method

```
static void test(Integer i){
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000*Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

and compare output from this method using `parallelStream` and `stream`

Comment: The fact that `List.Stream()` processes data in order says more about the internals of the `List` than the behavior of `stream()`. A `Set`, for example, feeds a stream in no particular order.  `forEach()`, by definition, makes the stream unordered, and so one should never count on the implementation detail of `List` behavior to expect that elements would be processed in order. One should use `forEachOrdered`, not `forEach` to intentionally keep things ordered, and that will work for both `stream()` and `parallelStream()`